# How to remove duplicate "id" column values in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have several dataframes which I want to merge into only one big dataframe to build a classifier.

[This is the base dataframe, user_df_copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zar9K.png)

In this dataframe, there is the id column which indicates the client id. I have other dataframes [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODIZo.png), which have columns related to user_id column.

So, the goal is to merge these small dataframes into the user_df_copy, adding columns like subject_id and to have values only if the user_id matches to the main df id, otherwise, NaN. Problem is, in these small dataframes, the id's appear duplicated.

I also applied get_dummies to the subject_id column [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WURbn.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remove the links to images and include a formatted sample of your data / sample of output in your question. Formatted with `pd.DataFrame()` is best, but you can also just copy and paste a print out of the sample.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just drop duplicate rows in the smaller `DataFrame`s you can use:

`df.drop_duplicates(subset="id")`

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try that